# Integrate reselect in redux

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple search aplication, where depending by user input, it get the result on front end.

My redux code:

```js
import { persons } from "./persons";
import { createStore } from "redux";

//contant
export const SEARCH = {
  SEARCH_PERSON: "SEARCH_PERSON"
};
//action
export const searchPersonAction = (person) => {
  const personSearched = persons.filter((p) =>
    p.name.toLowerCase().includes(person.toLowerCase())
  );
  return {
    type: SEARCH.SEARCH_PERSON,
    payload: personSearched
  };
};
//reducer
const initialState = {
  name: persons
};

export const search = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SEARCH.SEARCH_PERSON:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
//store
export const store = createStore(search);
```

UI component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { searchPersonAction } from "./store";

const Search = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selector = useSelector((s) => s);
  const search = (e) => {
    const txt = e.target.value;
    dispatch(searchPersonAction(txt));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={search} placeholder="search" />
      <ul>
        {selector.name.map((p) => (
          <li key={p.name}>{p.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Now the application works properly, but i want to integrate in my application `reselect` library. I want to use reselect in filter logic.
**Question: Which changes should i add in my application code?**

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-monad-litc1?file=/src/Search.js:0-577

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the function in `useSelector` into `createSelector` from `reselect` which will memoise the selector values. You can do it like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { searchPersonAction } from "./store";

const memoiseSelector = createSelector(
  (s) => s.name,
  (name) => name
);

const Search = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const name = useSelector(memoiseSelector);
  const search = (e) => {
    const txt = e.target.value;
    dispatch(searchPersonAction(txt));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={search} placeholder="search" />
      <ul>
        {name?.map((p) => (
          <li key={p.name}>{p.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Further more examples you can check here on official [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors).

Comment: i changed, but it does not work https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-monad-litc1?file=/src/Search.js

Comment: could you help please?

Comment: I have updated the answer, I missed the second argument on createSelector. You can find updated implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-heyrovsky-66dvv?file=/src/Search.js:0-737.

Comment: I also I would suggest not to modify based on persons object you have in static file but the value that is in state. That should be single source of truth.

Comment: how `memoiseSelector` get data from outside? I tought that  i should pass data as parameter in `memoiseSelector`, like `memoiseSelector(data)`. I'm i right?

Comment: memoiseSelector is just a function to which the state is passed using useSelector. If you console.log(memoiseSelector). You will see it as function it self.

Comment: I have  one more question related to this context. Using `reselect` in the example above, did i improve the performance or  `reselect ` in my case does not help?

Comment: The reselect wouldnt call the function if your state is not changed. So it gives you a memoise advantage.