# Save data in a specific way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where user have to input data about it and after saving that `form`, the data should  be outputed in a certain form.

```js
const ParrentForm = () => {
  const [carNr, setCarNr] = useState([]);

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = values;
    const user = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      things: {
        cars: []
      }
    };
    console.log(user);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };
  const setFloorsNrHandler = (nr) => {
    setCarNr(Array.from({ length: nr }, (v, k) => k));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        name="main"
        initialValues={{ remember: true }}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      >
        <Form.Item
          label="First Name"
          name="firstName"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your first name!" }]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          label="Last Name"
          name="lastName"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your last name!" }]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name="nrOfCars"
          label="Cars"
          rules={[{ type: "number", min: 0, max: 15 }]}
        >
          <InputNumber onChange={setFloorsNrHandler} />
        </Form.Item>
        {carNr.map((f, k) => {
          return (
            <Form.Item key={k}>
              <InnerForm cKey={k} />
            </Form.Item>
          );
        })}
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParrentForm;
```

The expected data should look like this:

```js
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "M.",
  },
  "things": {
    "cars": [
      {
        "nr":  1,
        "carsList": [
          {
            "name": "Car 1",
            "nr": 1
          },
            {
            "name": "Audi",
            "nr": 2
          },
          ,
            {
            "name": "Mercedes",
            "nr": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nr":  2,
        "carsList": [
          {
            "name": "Bmw",
            "nr": 1  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to modify the data inside `onFinish` function to get the result above?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cache-o0g65?file=/OuterForm.js:136-1755

Answer (score 0):

First you have to destruct ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) the form values object combining with spread operator ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) to get the car-related values (I stored in variable `carValues`). After that, the only things left to do is manipulate with that variable, here I combined the use of `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.map`

There a part with `Number(key)`, because `Object.entries()` transforms object in to array of key-value pair, with key's type of string, so you have to cast it to `Number` first for  1-based index

```js
const onFinish = values => {
  const { firstName, lastName, nrOfCars, ...carValues } = values
  const cars = Object.entries(carValues).map(([key, value]) => ({
    nr: Number(key) + 1,
    carsList: (value.cars || []).map((car, carIndex) => ({
      nr: carIndex + 1,
      name: car.name
    }))
  }))
  const user = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    things: {
      cars
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2))
}
```

Forked codesandbox for implementation

[image: Edit polished-rain-w3cxw]

Comment: why if i add additional <input> in outter form, like: `<Form.Item
          label="pasword"
          name="pasword"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your password" }]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>`, i get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`..?

Comment: @AskMen my bad for the case when do not add any cars, please change `carsList: value.cars.` to `carsList: (value.cars || []).`. Updated answer also

Comment: doing this i get  as last item: {
        "nr": null,
        "carsList": []
      }  do you know why?

Comment: could you help?

Comment: @AskMen I tried in my sandbox and see no problem, could you provide the steps that reproduce your unexpected behavior, as well as your updated sandbox link?

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428679/send-a-request-inside-a-rendered-list-of-elements-in-reactjs